# How to retrieve app logs when running UITests?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, ui-automation, uitest

As stated, any way of retrieving App Logs, not just the test logs, using Xcode 14? all I see in xcresult files are the Runner's logs, but I need the app logs as well both when running via Xcode or through cli

Answer (score 0):

On **Xcode 15** `Reveal Diagnostics in Finder` context menu is gone, which seems VERY ODD. I'm currently facing the same problem as described in [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/741646) Apple dev forum thread and I opened a Feeback Report FB13615178.

In the meantime, you can use `xcresulttool`.

Get the object graph to get the IDs for the objects you want to export.

```bash
xcrun xcresulttool graph --path YourResult.xcresult/ > graph.log
```

Search for `StandardOutputAndStandardError` to see where it is in the graph. Get its ID and export it:

```bash
xcrun xcresulttool export \
--type directory \
--path YourResult.xcresult/ \
--output-path ./Output \
--id <ID-HERE>
```

I believe we can put together a script to automatically extract the logs on a CI environment - this is our current goal. Please share if you have any progress.

---

On **Xcode 14**: Open the `.xcresult` in Xcode, right-click a test, and select `Reveal Diagnostics in Finder`. You should see your simulator(s) folder(s) and inside of one of those you'll see `StandardOutputAndStandardError-bundle-id.txt` file.

Comment: "I'm having this problem too" is not a valid answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.